A Nicer/Faster way to compute the determinant?
Is there a faster or nicer way to compute the determinant?
It's from a book called Linear Algebra Challenging Problems.
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 & x+2 & x+3 \\ 
x+8 & x+9 & x+4 \\ 
x+7 & x+6 & x+5
\end{vmatrix}$$
The numbering is in a spiral, but I don't see a pattern here when computing the determinant.
Is there actually a sneaky trick to this?

Subtract the first row from the second and the third to get rid of many $x$'s.

with many line/row operations, you get 3 zeros quite easily in your determinant
